# Default value for Gradle buildConfigField boolean used across flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a number of flavors in my app, and I want to set a boolean buildConfigField for a subset of them. Is there a way to avoid having to add the field to every flavor? Ideally my build.gradle would look like the following:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
    }

    ....

    flavor4 {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "DISABLE_SOMETHING", "true"
    }

    flavor5 {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "DISABLE_SOMETHING", "true"
    }

    ....

    flavor8 {
    }
}
```

So in my app I can just go

```
if (BuildConfig.DISABLE_SOMETHING) {
    //disable stuff
}
```

However, compilation fails when I try to build with, for example, `flavor1`, as it can't find the field. I don't want to have to remember to add this to every new flavor I create. Are there any ways around this?

Comment: @Selvin nice spot, I didn't see that when I was searching. Thanks

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can use `defaultConfig` for this (inside `android{}`)

```
defaultConfig {
  buildConfigField "boolean", "DISABLE_SOMETHING", "true"
}
```

Comment: Also we can use `buildConfigField 'boolean', 'isEnableFeature', "false"`

Comment: When I try this, I get that string "true" can't be cast to a boolean

Comment: I'm getting `Cause: defaultConfig contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled.
To enable the feature, add the following to your module-level build.gradle:
android.buildFeatures.buildConfig true`. Any idea why the feature is disabled by default?