# How to print log inside release aar

Tags: android, logging, logcat, dexguard

I want to build an apk and inside it I need to use release aar inside it.
The aar must be release build since I need to shrink and obfuscate it.

But I would like to print the log for network log to see if my obfuscation will not bother the request payload.

I tried to use System.out.println, but I could not see any log from aar.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Write it to a file

Comment: You can use Timber logging library(or any other library) to save the logs in a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gradle build config field to enable/disable log print.
[Default value for Gradle buildConfigField boolean used across flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048270/)
First create a log wrapper function with a boolean parameter, true means enable log print. And then you can create an init funtcion for your aar, in which you can set log enable parameter.
Meanwhile define a build config field in your app.gradle:

```
 debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_LOG", "true"
    }
 release {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_LOG", "false"
    }
```

Then just call `aar.init(BuildConfig.ENABLE_LOG)` on `Application.oncreate()`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to turn it on in the `manifest`/`build.gradle`. [Enable LogCat on Release Build in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610936/enable-logcat-on-release-build-in-android-studio)

There have been a few changes to it over the years so you may have to look at more than the accepted answer.

You can also use this library https://github.com/tony19/logback-android

It can create log files on the device, that you can open and inspect.

Comment: the apk is debug apk,  but the aar I used in libs folder is release build aar,  which build. gradle should I check?

Comment: Your library as the app in debug won't stop the logs.

Comment: I want to print the log in the library, and the library is now release build.
Now I set the `android:debuggable="true"` in dist/SampleApp/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
But it still does not print any log.
Did you try that way and can confirm it works?

Comment: Francis has the right answer though, for security reasons when you release your app, turn it off..